# Let $S$ and $T$ be subspaces of vector space $V$. Determine whether $S \cup T$ and $S \cap T$ are subspaces of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Let $S$ and $T$ be subspaces of vector space $V$. Prove or disprove that
>
> (a)$S \cup T$ (b) $S \cap T$
>
> are subspaces of $V$

My attempt

$(a) $

Let
$$V = \{(a,b,0)^{T} \mid a,b \in \mathbb R\}$$
and
$$S = \{(a,0,0)^{T} \mid a \in \mathbb R\}$$
and
$$T = \{(0,b,0)^{T} \mid b \in \mathbb R\}$$

We define vector addition and scalar multiplication as *usual* vector addition and multiplication.

It can be shown (by checking 10 axioms) that $V$ is a vector space, and both $S$ and $T$ are subspaces of $V$.

$S \cup T =  \{(a,0,0)^{T}, (0,a,0)^{T}\mid a \in \mathbb R\}$

Take two arbitrary vectors, say $(1,0,0)^{T}$ and $(0,1,0)^{T}$. Both vectors are in $S \cup T$

We have

$$ (1,0,0)^{T} + (0,1,0)^{T} = (1,1,0)^{T} $$

But $(1,1,0)^{T}$ is not in $S \cup T$, therefore $S \cup T$ is not a subspace of $V$.

$(b)$

Consider set $S \cap T$. Take two arbitrary vectors, say $\bf u$ and $\bf v$, such that $\mathbf{u,v} \in S \cap T$

Required to show that $\bf u + v$ $\in$ $S \cap T$

Since $\bf u,v$ are in  $S \cap T $, then they must be in $S$. And since $S$ is subspace, then $\bf u + v$ must be in $S$ as well.

Applying the same reasoning, we can conclude that $\bf u + v$ is in $T$.

Since $\bf u + v$ is both in $S$ and $T$, by definition of intersection, we conclude that $\bf u + v$ $\in S \cap T$

We also need to show the closure under scalar multiplication. (Very similar to the steps above)

Consider an arbitrary vector $\bf u$ such that $\bf u \in S \cap T$, and an arbitrary scalar $k$

Since $\mathbf u \in S \cap T$, then $\mathbf u \in S$ and $\mathbf u \in T$. Because $S,T$ are subspaces, $k \mathbf u \in S$ and $k \mathbf u \in T$ and therefore $k \mathbf u \in S \cap T$

We have closure under scalar addition and multiplication, therefore $S \cap T$ is a subspace of $V$.

---

Admittedly, this is verbose, but is it correct?

Comment: Yes: I would say that the explanation is well done and indeed correct.

Comment: Your answer is correct, however, your first counterexample is a little difficult, as everything you are doint works fine in a two-dimensional vector space.

Comment: Yes, correct.  (a) was a bit overcomplicated, $V$ could have been simply $\Bbb R^2$.